# How do I make a list a key value in a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I need to make a dictionary where you can reference [[1,2],[3,4]] --> ([1,2]:0, [2,3]:0)
I've tried different ways but I can't use a list in a dictionary. So i tried using tuples, but its still the same. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you are trying to use a list as a key I think you may have the wrong implementation for your algorithm.

Comment: *So i tried using tuples, but its still the same* Please show us your code!

Comment: *Why do you want to do this?* If the content of the lists isn't going to change, and you want to use the content as the key in your dict, then convert the list to tuple and use that as a key, as others have suggested. On the other hand, if you're going to be changing the content of the list but still want to be able to map the list to the same value in the dictionary, then call the `id()` builtin function on your list and use the result of that as your key. These are two very different use cases and you haven't given enough information for us to determine which approach solves your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use tuples:

```
dict.fromkeys((tuple(i) for i in [[1,2],[3,4]]), 0)
```

or (for python2.7+)

```
{tuple(i): 0 for i in [[1,2], [3,4]]}
```

Edit:

Reading the comments, OP probably want to count occurrences of a list:

```
>>> collections.Counter(tuple(i) for i in [[1,2], [1,2], [3,4]])
Counter({(1, 2): 2, (3, 4): 1})
```

Comment: Is there any way to change the 0? Like, if you have a list of [[1,2],[1,2],[2,3]], I need it to return [[1:2]:2, [2:3]:1]?

Comment: @user1828072 Of course, just write `1` as the last argument instead of `0`

Comment: @user1828072 Oh, if you need to count the number of times a list is inside another, you'll probably need `collections.Counter`

Comment: In the first version, I prefer `dict((tuple(i),0) for i in [[1,2],[3,4]])` rather than using the classmethod -- But that's just a matter of taste I suppose.  (It's also closer to the syntax used to create the dict-comp in py2.7)

Comment: As you can probably tell, im quite new at this! I mean, the last number '0', instead of it being 0, can it return the number of occurances? For example: y = [[1,2],[1,2],[2,3]] ; there are two [1:2], is there a way to use a variable to return something like:[1,2]:2 instead?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @mgilson that will make tuples to be unpacked... Unlike `fromkeys`

Comment: @JBernardo -- What do you mean it will make the tuples be unpacked?  They result in exactly the same dictionary (try it)

Comment: Y is a user input, where they can enter as many 'lists' as they want, and I need to find the mode of each list

Comment: @mgilson `(tuple(i), 0)` is a tuple you created that will be unpacked

Comment: @JBernardo -- I don't see where the unpacking is done.  if you pass an iterable which contains 2-element iterables to `dict`, each 2-element tuple gets turned into a `key`-`value` pair (which is *exactly* what your dict comprehension is doing).  `dict(mydictinstance.items())` is effectively `dict.copy()`.  Are you referring to the efficiency of the whole thing?  I would doubt that there would be much difference in that regard for moderately sized lists and I'd take the readability anyway :-)

Comment: I agree with the occurrences count interpretation. If OP doesn't have 2.7+, an alternative is:

>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> mylist = [[1,2],[1,2],[3,4]]
>>> mydict = defaultdict(int)
>>> for item in mylist:
        mydict[tuple(item)] += 1

Comment: @mgilson so, the first element becomes the key and the second the value. This I call to unpack a tuple into 2 variables. If you pass just once the value, this operation (create a tuple then unpack it) will be avoided

Comment: @JBernardo -- Right, I think I see what you're saying now.  You're arguing from an efficiency standpoint and I'm arguing from a readability standpoint.  Just one other comment -- You could be in for quite a surprise if you used `dict.fromkeys` with a *mutable* object as the second argument, but that's not an issue for this question.

Comment: At the risk of being sound confused,(which i probably am), what does collection do? Sorry, im quite new to python!

Comment: @user1828072 `collections` is a module and `Counter` is a class that implement counting of objects you give to them. It works just like a dictionary and store the number of times you fed some object to it

Comment: @mgilson BTW, the second snippet does exactly that only in Py2.7+ syntax

Comment: @user1828072 No, this is just part of the string representation of the object. It behaves just like a dict that replaces missing keys with `0`. BTW, it's simpler to use `collections.Counter` as I wrote... If the answer solved your problem, you can click the "tick" mark under the vote count

Comment: Okay, Thanks alot JBernardo! Greatly Appreciated!

Comment: Yes, the Counter solution is more elegant; the defaultdict version is just another way if Counter isn't available.

Answer (score 3):

Lists can't be used as dictionary keys since they aren't hashable (probably because they can be mutated so coming up with a reasonable hash function is impossible).  `tuple` however poses no problem:

```
d = {(1,2):0, (3,4):0}
```

Note that in your example, you seem to imply that you're trying to build a dictionary like this:

```
((1,2):0, (3,4):0)
```

That won't work.  You need curly brackets to make a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

`([1,2]:0, [2,3]:0)` is not a dictionary. I think you meant to use: `{(1,2):0, (2,3):1}`

Comment: It looks like we had the same idea at the same time -- however, your second example won't work either since you're using lists as keys which won't fly.

Comment: Right, it looks like we also noticed that at the same time too! I edited it to reflect. Thanks!